# What I need to verify contract with open-source license?

Tags: contract-development, remix, ether, etherscan

i m deployed contract in etherscan mainnet. i m verify it with open-source license like (MIT, GNU). now the problem were i don't know were to define license in etherscan ?? and etherscan will validate license when we update the token profile ??

contract example :- https://etherscan.io/address/0x230451cc96eb02df59fb2dc99dd1b701fd119329#code

Answer (score 1):

raj.
I guess you can pick a license type on the Verify page https://ropsten.etherscan.io/verifyContract?a={yourcontractaddress}

Comment: yes Oleg Kondrakhanov, but the question was i need to provide this license in my website or git repo ??. And ehterscan can validate this license in my website or git repo at time of profile summery updation ??

Comment: Probably that's the type of questions you might want ask etherscan support themselves.